# Can I put up a joke sign on my private land that reads "Active Minefield"?

Tags: united-states, freedom-of-speech

I own a few acres (in the USA) and want to put up a joke sign that says "Active Minefield". A friend mentioned that is illegal.  I am not so sure, ergo looking for opinion or references.

I understand classic free speech examples like you can not yell "Fire" in a movie theater.  Since this sign is on private land and will only be visible when you are on the property, I would love to have a legal opinion.

My alternative is to put up a sign "Keep Out: Testing Lasers from Space" which is a derivative of this idea and (IMO) would be considered humor.  I know there is a line, how and where is that "line" defined?

Comment: What state are you in?

Comment: You can put up a sign that is true, for example "Warning! This field is infested with an outbreak of creeping fescue". Or "Warning. Radiactive radon gas is present in this field."

Comment: Don't do it in Laos or the Falklands or Kosovo... those guys have no sense of humor...

Comment: **Trespassers will be shot. Survivors will be shot again.** ... "with respect to your own property, so long as you haven't agreed to any limitations on the appearance of your home (such as through a Homeowners Association or deed restriction), you're free to put up any signs you want, regardless of how violent, offensive, or profane they may be to others. That's the First Amendment at work — it limits the government's ability to regulate speech — so yes, a sign threatening to shoot trespassers is perfectly legal." https://www.huffpost.com/entry/does-posting-trespassers_b_7889192

Comment: Regardless of legal issues, this is a spectacularly bad idea in case emergency services ever need to come to your property.

Comment: Personally I would probably instead write: Warning! This area has not been cleared as free of anti-personell mines. Walk only on marked paths.

Comment: @bdb484 I am in Colorado, currently Park County (South Park fame).  No HOA.  Very wild west compared to neighboring counties, with almost no police presence at all (esp after 7p)

Comment: @Mazura I am aware of that, I am curious about pushing the limits, may go with "No Landmines" instead haha.  I do fly drones in the trees at stupid speeds (30-50mph), so there is a real danger, here's some practice runs in the "Minefield" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vxm9tYxIGgM

Comment: I'd strongly argue from a moral perspective not to put anything on such a sign that might make someone think an identical sign elsewhere is also a joke when it isn't. If you're going to joke, it should be obvious to everyone regardless of context. For that reason, your alternative is much better. My personal favorite though is "No Trespassing: Prosecutors Will Be Violated"

Comment: @Mazura: of course, if a trespasser was some day shot on the property, such a sign very easily be used to persuade a jury that it was murder rather than self defense.

Comment: Walking in a field next to my house in France (next to a large city), I jokingly said to a friend from Scotland *make sure to follow the path, there are mines that the cows did not step on yet* and he froze still. he was not entertained at all, even though the idea of having mines there was, rationally, completely insane. Better go for the laser things, if anything (but as @gerrit noted, this sis a spectacularly bad ides in some cases)

Comment: @gerrit That was my first thought--the firefighters will not like it.  I wouldn't be surprised if the police find some way to make it into some sort of interfering with firefighters offense.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At the federal level, [18 USC 35](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/35) is as close as you can get:

> (a) Whoever imparts or conveys or causes to be imparted or conveyed
> false information, knowing the information to be false, concerning an
> attempt or alleged attempt being made or to be made, to do any act
> which would be a crime prohibited by this chapter or chapter 97 or
> chapter 111 of this title shall be subject to a civil penalty of not
> more than $1,000 which shall be recoverable in a civil action brought
> in the name of the United States.

However, the false information has to have a specific character. [Ch. 97](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/part-I/chapter-97) regards trains and mass transportation systems (entering to commit a crime, terrorist attacks). I assume you don't have railroad lines running through your property. [Ch. 111](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/part-I/chapter-111) regards shipping, presumably not relevant to your land. Finally, [Ch. 2](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/part-I/chapter-2) ("this chapter") regards aircraft and motor vehicles: [18 USC 33](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/33) prohibits endangering... so for the sake of discussion, perhaps there is a false threat against motor vehicles (assuming there is a highway near your property). So...

> (a) Whoever willfully, with intent to endanger...causes to be placed
> any explosive...in proximity to, any motor vehicle...

is a criminal. Therefore conveying false information that an explosive is in proximity to a motor vehicle is also against the law. That's probably close enough to warrant hiring an attorney before you end up arrested on a federal charge.

Para. (a) makes this action a matter for a civil penalty ($1,000 limit), whereas para. (b) of §35 makes it a crime if you act "willfully and maliciously, or with reckless disregard for the safety of human life". You joke would not rise to the level of willful and malicious, but it could easily be found to be negligent, so you could get a civil penalty.

Comment: Very cool work.  See my other comment below for a little context, but this is the legal thinking I was interested in (as well as conceptual). This joke idea stems from my grandfather in NYC who had a notice on his car to keep it form getting towed. This is not a joke, it said "Sparkplug attached to gas tank, any attempt to move will cause it to explode".  That was a loooong time ago.  Thanks/accepted.

Comment: Why "_Therefore conveying false information that an explosive is in proximity to a motor vehicle is also against the law._"? In essence, why lying about having committed a crime is itself a crime?

Comment: The standard political rationale is that false alarms waste public resources.

Comment: @Greendrake, in this case, I suspect what we're seeing is an unexpected interaction between two laws.

Comment: @Greendrake "I am currently committing the crime of lying about committing this crime."

Comment: The sign could safely convey truthful, albeit ambiguous information - something like : *"WARNING : AREA HAS NOT BEEN CHECKED FOR LANDMINES.  NO TRESPASSING"*

Comment: This sounds like it would only be illegal to post the sign if it were illegal to have explosives on private property. I'd think that would depend on local laws, and/or licensing.

Comment: Since _both_ quoted paragraphs are labelled (a), "Para. (a) makes this" could do with clarification.

Answer (score 32):

> My alternative is to put up a sign "Keep Out: Testing Lasers from
> Space" which is a derivative of this idea and (IMO) would be
> considered humor. I know there is a line, how and where is that "line"
> defined?

This distinction captures the key point. If your sign stating "Active Mine Field" would, in the overall context, be understood as humor and not as a true statement of fact, it will be protected by the First Amendment.

If, however, someone is basically defrauded by a sign, because it appears to a reasonable person to be making a true statement of fact upon which a person reasonably relies to their detriment (or perhaps could reasonably rely to their detriment for criminal law purposes), then it is probably not protected.

For example, suppose that your "Active Minefield" sign causes the fire department, when responding to a wildfire next door to your property, to take the long way around your property or to call in the bomb squad at great expense. You could have civil liability as a result. Similarly, if the fire department refused to respond to a fire on your property due to such a sign, your insurance company might have a ground to deny your insurance claim for damages that a prompt fire department response could have prevented.

And @user6726 points out circumstances where there could be criminal liability, although there, as in the civil case, the First Amendment would require those criminal statutes to be employed in enough of a common sense fashion to only be invoked in cases where a reasonable person would believe the sign to be purporting to be a true statement of fact in the overall context of the situation, in order to withstand an "as applied" constitutional challenge to a facially valid statute.

So, a "space lasers" sign (at least as of 2022 when there are no such things) would probably not give rise to legal or civil liability, but an "Active Minefield" sign without something involved in the presentations to clearly indicate that it is a joke (or a fictional depiction for temporary theatrical purposes, for example) to a reasonable person, could result in civil or criminal liability.

Similarly, if the sign was very artistic and also had pictures of Bugs Bunny and Coyote chasing each other, and images of obviously fake "land mines", or if the sign were accompanied by a picture of cow turds everywhere that made clear that the "minefield" was a field full of excrement rather than high explosives, it wouldn't be actionable.

Comment: Well said.  The sign would "protect" a wooded area, technically our leach field.  As for visibility, you would need to be on the property and past various "no trespassing" signs to see my humor.  Still, I generally agree and wanted to get a good legal sniff for this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding (IANAL) is that mines are legal but heavily regulated (to the point that they are de-facto illegal).  If you pay all the fees, fill out all the forms, jump through all the hoops you can legally mine your property.

The law (as I understand it) requires you to clearly identify areas where mines are present (i.e., post those "Active Minefield" signs).  It does not require you to not post areas where mines are not present.

Indeed, I suspect that many of those "mine fields" near the Korean DMZ (both sides) are not mined.  The "defenders" know (or should know) which "mine fields" are really mined and which are not.  The "attackers" can not be sure.  This is in compliance with international law as long as all the "real mine fields" are adequately signed.

However, there are a variety of disadvantages.  One that others have not mentioned is that an "Active Mine Field" sign might be primae facie evidence that you have a mine field.  The government can quickly check its records and determine that if you have a mine field it is an illegal mine field.  Let's take this to a judge and get a warrant.  We will call in specialists and (extremely carefully) dig up every square inch of your property looking for those illegal mines.

Looks like you do not have any mines.  Your property is a mess - not the government's problem.  It is hard to imagine any legal irregularities escaping the extreme scrutiny that your search team put your property through.  Here are a bunch of citations for the violations noted.

Comment: That is an interesting take on this particular topic.  I am thinking I may just change the sign to "Keep Out: Hidden Bear Traps".  Almost as bad...

Comment: @Marc I would recommend "WARNING:  GOVERNMENT AUDIT ZONE", "BUREAUCRATS MAY BE ARMED", "PAY YOUR TAXES", "WOULD YOU LIKE TO TALK ABOUT JESUS?", "EAT MORE VEGETABLES AND LESS MEAT".  These signs will discourage trespassers without giving law enforcement prima facie evidence of a crime.

Comment: I would post this sign (https://www.compliancesigns.com/pd/osha-notice-u-s-government-property-no-trespassing-sign-one-34483?gs=9.40&utm_term=&utm_campaign=SSS+-+CTC+-+Shopping+-+Smart+-+No+Trespass+%26+Security&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_acc=1231952908&hsa_cam=11759658442&hsa_grp=117994791830&hsa_ad=483518170033&hsa_src=u&hsa_tgt=pla-1051424700363&hsa_kw=&hsa_mt=&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpcOTBhCZARIsAEAYLuUL1zzgJFq1jmUHTjRM35DeeYn84QHQkW2VdBz2DZeGNRyqxPrQO34aAnH8EALw_wcB) as a joke.  It says  "US GOVERNMENT PROPERTY.  NO TRESPASSING ... PROSECUTION ..."

Comment: This is also a good one https://www.compliancesigns.com/pd/warning-restricted-area-title-18-u-s-c-1382-sign-nhe-16117?gs=53.80&utm_term=&utm_campaign=SSS+-+CTC+-+Shopping+-+Smart+-+No+Trespass+%26+Security&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_acc=1231952908&hsa_cam=11759658442&hsa_grp=117994791830&hsa_ad=483518170033&hsa_src=u&hsa_tgt=pla-1051424700363&hsa_kw=&hsa_mt=&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpcOTBhCZARIsAEAYLuWAxwoYVxs4fw3euKsP06ljuhvTyf1NM65_aqeLKXOktQzs3wI7EZcaAvjGEALw_wcB

Comment: https://www.compliancesigns.com/pd/osha-notice-military-training-in-progress-sign-one-37314 "Military Training In Progress"

Comment: lol @emory.  I prefer my own: "Any agents of the state, local, or federal government are required to relinquish Qualified Immunity while on this property."

Comment: @Marc it is far more preferable to joke signs that may increase liability "Gee your honor.  I took the sign seriously and it meant he had an illegal mine field."  But how about a sign that says "The right of the people to be secure in their persons, houses, papers, and effects, against unreasonable searches and seizures, shall not be violated, and no Warrants shall issue, but upon probable cause, supported by Oath or affirmation, and particularly describing the place to be searched, and the persons or things to be seized."

Comment: Then make them each sign unique somehow (different colors?) so they form a system of landmarks.  Then use the landmarks when cross-examining law enforcement.  "So you entered the property approximately 50 yards from the RED 'The right of the people to be secure in their persons, houses, papers, and effects ...' sign"